# Multi label tool-tip in Chart.js

Tags: chart.js, chartjs-2.6.0

Recently I moved an old project depending on Chart.js from v1 to v2.

But I am unable to recreate the multi-label tooltip like shown below.
[image: chart.js]

In v1 this feature was enabled by default.
Does anyone know what option I would have to change in order to archive this.

My code so far.

```
new Chart(document.getElementById('mainChart'), {
        type: 'line',
        data: {
          labels: labels,
          datasets: [
            { data: data, label: "Expenses", fill: false
          ]
        },
        options: {
          animation: { duration: 0 },
          hover: { animationDuration: 0 },
          responsiveAnimationDuration: 0
        }
      });
```

Comment: Your code sample seems to be missing a closing bracket after `fill: false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be set with the [`mode`](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/interactions/modes.html#interaction-modes) option in the tooltips section.
Setting the mode to `index` is likely the mode you are looking for.

```
  new Chart(document.getElementById('mainChart'), {
    type: 'line',
    data: {
      labels: labels,
      datasets: [
        { data: data, label: "Expenses", fill: false }
      ]
    },
    options: {
      animation: { duration: 0 },
      hover: { animationDuration: 0 },
      responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
      tooltips: { mode: 'index' }             
    }
  });
```

Below a sample with `mode: 'index'`:

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById('chartJSContainer'), {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        labels: ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6"],
        datasets: [{
         data: [7, 11, 5, 8, 3, 7],
            label: "Income",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
          }, {
         data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
            label: "Expenses",
            fill: false,
            backgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
            borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          }
          ]
        },
        options: {
          animation: {
            duration: 0
          },
          hover: {
            animationDuration: 0
          },
          responsiveAnimationDuration: 0,
          tooltips: {
           mode: 'index'
          }
        }
      });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.7.1/Chart.bundle.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
</body>
```